# Getting "success":1 in PHP, but push notification is not recieved in device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
<?php
include './func.php';

$c = getDB();

$op = p("op");



 $title=$_POST['title']; 

if ($op == "register")
{
    $firebaseId = p("firebase_id");
    $c->query("insert into ids values ('$firebaseId')");
}

if ($op == "get_app_details")
{
    $appId = p("app_id");

    // Select Sorgusundan Tek Satir Veri Dondurmek
    // $r'de Bir Satirin Tum Verisi Tutulur
    $r = $c->query("select * from applications where id = $appId")->fetch_assoc();
    toJSON($r);
}

if ($op == "get_all_applications")
{
    // Select Sorgusundan Tum Verileri Dondurmek
    // $rs'de Tum Tablo Verisi Tutulur
    $rs = $c->query("select * from applications");

    $arr = array();
    // Tablodaki Satirlari Tek Tek Don Ve Arraye Ekle
    while ($r = $rs->fetch_assoc())
        $arr[] = $r;

    toJSON($arr);
}



$apiKey ="AAAA_1EwCSM:APA***********jmy9q725Ca7w3sJI01***************GAPtf1Jv1TxZYgwIEIY6hH35Wf0lRCmAEl7HxSB_oaIJyhC6lQMmXvwC1J4PpVIS6K9Jg";

$fb_endpoint = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$headers = array('Authorization:key=' . $apiKey, 'Content-Type:application/json');

 $token = $c->query("select * from ids");
$meli = mysqli_fetch_array($token);
$string =$meli['firebase_id'];

   $data = array(
                'title' =>$title,
                'message' =>'',
                'subtitle' => '',
                'tickerText' => '',
                'msgcnt' => 1,
                'vibrate' => 1
            );



$fields = array('data' => $data, 'registration_ids' => array($string), 'delay_while_idle' => true, 'priority' => 'high', 'content_available' => true );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fb_endpoint); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//header("Content-Type: application/json");
//echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$res = json_decode($result);

print_r( $_POST );
echo "\r\n";
echo $result;



?>
```

this is my code is working , also I  have no problem about getting device's token. It is working I got success:1 but My device has not get any notification 
what are you recommend me. ?

```
"multicast_id":7984627576959961401,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1482750065457266%f126618ef9fd7ecd"}]}
```

My JAVA

message service:

```
public class MesajServisi extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


  String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
  //          String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


            android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        //notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("title");
           notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        //    notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
            //notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.)
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

        }
    }
```

ID SERVICE:

```
public class KayitServisi extends FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    String newToken = "";

    public void onTokenRefresh()
    {
        newToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.e("x","Cihaz ID : "+newToken);

        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new AsyncTask<String,String,String>()
                {
                    protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Jsoup.connect("http://192.168.1.18/server/mobile.php")
                                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                                    .timeout(30000)

                                    .data("firebase_id",newToken)
                                    .post();
                            Log.e("x","ID Server'a Kayit Edildi");

                        } catch (Exception e) { Log.e("x","DoInBG Ex : "+e.toString()); }
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```